# To skip chrome app on the stack when the back button is pressed in order to go back to my app

Tags: android, button, navigation, stack, back

A chrome app is launched by my app via an Intent.Action_View with an uri. The chrome app will in turn immediately launch an ebay app because the uri provided. So I like to make it so that when a user presses a back button, it will bring him back to my app instead of the chrome app.

So basically the stack is: my app -launched-> chrome app -launched-> ebay app.

When the user presses the back button, is there a way to allow it to skip the chrome app.

Or is there a way to force chrome app to close itself after it has launched the ebay app?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is possible. However, I would suggest you should use Chrome custom tabs or webview in your application instead of launching the chrome intent because user may or may not have chrome in his phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not have to be chrome. It could be just a web ui. Do you know how to launch an ebay app directly with an given uri that has an item view info? This would cut out the 'middle man'. So ideally, if i could figure it out, my app would launch the ebay app only if it exists otherwise it will just launch the web ui for the ebay site.

Comment: The following code 
`PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ebay.mobile");
        if (null != appStartIntent)
        {
            startActivity(appStartIntent);
        }
        else {
            //App doesn't exist
        }`